# PHP - Call class like call_user_func

Tags: php, class, call

I have 2 variables :

```
$class : contains the name of the class
$params : contains the parameters to initialize the class like ["key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"]
```

And I want to call a class like the function call_user_func() do with functions

ie :

```
$classObject = call_class($class, $params);
// Do the same that: 
$classObject = new $class("value1", "value2");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use array argument unpacking, if you're running PHP >= 5.6:

```
$classObject = new $class(...$params);
```

Another would be to use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
$classObject = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

call_user_func_array lets you invoke the class methods.

```
<?php

class Foo {
  public function bar($param1, $param2) {
    echo $param1.$param2;
  }
}

$className = 'Foo';

call_user_func_array(array(new $className, 'bar'), array('Hello', 'World !'));
```

Comment: Your answer is right but the Mark Baker's answer is OOP

Comment: @ClémentLaffitte agreed.